# SKU number needed from vendor

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone have an idea why our vendor needs our sku number for a new app?
We bring the app in appstore by ourself and maybe I´m wrong but the sku is not needed for building the app or upload it to the store - it´s only in itunes connect not part of the app or plist and so on.

Everything they need is the bundle identifier in my opinion, but I think it should also be possible to change it self in the plist after we got the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SKU number is a setting in iTunnesConnect only, and it is ment as your internal reference number only.

We just use the App Bundle ID there, since that is how we reference the project internally.

Comment: ok thank you. I think they ask for the bundle ID for the plist.

Comment: Editing the plist after building the app is also possible, isn´t it?

Comment: Yes you can change the info.plist file, but once the app has been submitted to the appstore you can't change the bundle ID or SKU. Also you can't edit the info.plist from code, since it's in the application bundle which is readonly.

Answer (score 2):

I found on MacRumors:

> On the "Publishing on the App Store" video from ADC itunes, we can see
>   the SKU ID of the example application and this SKU is:
>   TOUCH_FIGHTER_001 for an application which call touch fighter (of
>   course). It's unique for an application, every application have an
>   unique ID and ID is independent of the app version. It's can't be
>   changed and users can't see this ID.
>
> Assume you will eventually have over a hundred apps in the store, and
>   you need a concise sort field to sort all the data by app in your
>   company sales spreadsheet or accounting program.
>
> So give each unique app a unique tag (maybe 7 digits or characters,
>   like the part number on the iPhone Box: MB716LL, etc.

Or you can just use a number. I used 1000 for my first app .